# Rise/Fall time in Microwind

Tags: inverter, cmos

Is there a way to measure rise/fall time, 10%-90% in Microwind?
What is shown is the 50% propagation delay I presume.

[image]

Comment: don't know that program, but what's available beyond the "More" button?

Comment: the more is used to scroll the time axis. there doesn't seem to be other measuring options.

Comment: well, then that answers your question, doesn't it? (unless the "Eye Diagramm" page has better info)

Comment: That's a really spartanic signal view, by the way. do you have any export functionality for the simulated signals, so that a more useful visualization program can be used? Typical file formats include names like "VCD".

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find anything intuitive on it. I'm using it for a undergraduate design coursework. If there aren't anyone familiar with it I will check with my convenor. Thanks for the suggestion anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you click and drag on the graph from the start point to the end point  (i.e from the edge rise at 4.0 to where the sets at 5V level) it will measure the time of the line you drew in yellow (ns) and the frequency in grey MHz.[image: measuring various points]
Try to be as accurate as possible for it is very sensitive, if you mess up you can press the "Reset" button and try again.